# Database from entities or entities from database

Tags: java, jpa, dbase

I use jpa framework in java. I was used to create dbase schema first. Then to create reflecting classes in java application. Should I create first entity clases then create dbase schema from these? Which approach is beter?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First know the whole Data model and then create the necessary entity classes accordingly.